# [Android][expo][@react-native-voice/voice] [TypeError: Cannot read property 'startSpeech' of null]

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo, voice-recognition

I'm trying to `record user voice` and transform it to text in react-native app, using `expo`, `typescript`, and `@react-native-voice/voice` package.

I have imported the library into my project, but when I try to launch the `start` or `stop` function, I get below errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startSpeech' of null

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopSpeech' of null
```

I have tried everything, but I don't understand why the library doesn't seem to load correctly...
I am using `Android 13`. Perhaps there is a version incompatibility?

Please help, i dont find any solutions...

Here's the code for voice recording:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
    import Voice from '@react-native-voice/voice';
    
    const SpeechToText = () => {
        const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
        const [speechText, setSpeechText] = useState('');
    
        const onSpeechStartHandler = () => {
            setIsRecording(true);
            setSpeechText('');
        };
    
        const onSpeechEndHandler = () => {
            setIsRecording(false);
        };
    
        const onSpeechResultsHandler = (event: any) => {
            setSpeechText(event.value[0]);
        };
    
        const startSpeechToText = async () => {
            try {
                await Voice.start('en-US');
                onSpeechStartHandler();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
    
        const stopSpeechToText = async () => {
            try {
                await Voice.stop();
                onSpeechEndHandler();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPressIn={startSpeechToText}
                    onPressOut={stopSpeechToText}
                    disabled={isRecording}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Press and hold to speak</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.speechText}>{speechText}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
```

In `app.json`, here is my configuration:

```
    {
      "expo": {
        [....]
        "android": {
          "adaptiveIcon": {
            "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
          },
          "permissions": [
            "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
          ]
        },
        "plugins": [
          [
            "@react-native-voice/voice",
            {
              "microphonePermission": "CUSTOM: Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access the microphone",
              "speechRecognitionPermission": "CUSTOM: Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to securely recognize user speech"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

here is my **package.json**:

````
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "test": "jest --watchAll"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-voice/voice": "^3.2.4",
        "expo": "~48.0.11",
        "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
        "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
        "expo-permissions": "^14.1.1",
        "expo-router": "^1.5.2",
        "expo-speech": "^11.1.1",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
        "expo-system-ui": "~2.2.1",
        "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.6",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.18.10"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.71.5",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4"
      },
      "private": true
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

The import statement for the Voice module is missing a default import. Instead of:

```
import Voice from '@react-native-voice/voice';
```

it should be:

```
import Voice from '@react-native-voice/voice/dist/voice';
```

This is because the Voice module exports a default object with a Voice property, so we need to import that specific property. The dist/voice path specifies the file where the Voice property is defined.

Also, the onSpeechResultsHandler function assumes that the event object has a value property, which might not be the case. To avoid potential errors, we can use optional chaining to check if the property exists:

```
setSpeechText(event?.value?.[0] || '');
```

This sets the speechText state to the first item in the value array, or an empty string if the value property or the first item in the array is undefined.

The error message suggests that the Voice module is not initialized properly or is not available at the time of calling the startSpeechToText and stopSpeechToText functions. This can happen if the Voice module is not imported correctly or if it is not yet loaded when these functions are called.

To fix this issue, you can try the following:

Make sure that the @react-native-voice/voice package is installed and imported correctly. You can check the package.json file to see if the package is listed as a dependency, and check the import statement to make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Ensure that the Voice module is loaded before calling the startSpeechToText and stopSpeechToText functions. You can add a check to see if the Voice module is loaded before calling these functions, like this:

```
const startSpeechToText = async () => {
    if (Voice) {
        try {
            await Voice.start('en-US');
            onSpeechStartHandler();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
};

const stopSpeechToText = async () => {
    if (Voice) {
        try {
            await Voice.stop();
            onSpeechEndHandler();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
};
```

This checks if the Voice module exists before calling the start and stop methods.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Weronika for your answer!

I tried changing it like this:

    import Voice from '@react-native-voice/voice/dist/voice';

But I get an error because the last "/voice" does not exist. However, I can do it like this:

    import Voice from '@react-native-voice/voice/dist';

`if (Voice)` condition is true, but unfortunately, I still have the same error as above.

I also tried using the test provided by the package (VoiceTest.tsx), but I still have the same problem...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure that the @react-native-voice/voice package is properly installed. You can check this by running npm ls @react-native-voice/voice in your project directory. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the import, your original import was fine (

```js
import Voice from "@react-native-voice/voice";
```

) You are using native library modules (such as Microphone access), so it's not going to work in expo or an emulator straight out of the box. You will need to run in development mode. For android using your mobile phone:

1. From the terminal: eas build --profile development --platform android
2. From the terminal: npx expo start --dev-client
3. Scan the QR code with your device

It should now work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this, is because the native components are missing this includes react native voice, you need to build them first.

You need to run.

```
npx expo prebuild
```

This will build the react native components. Then you need to run:

```
npx expo run:android
```

This will build a development version of the app to either an emulator or your phone. This build includes the required native components for @react-native-voice/voice to work properly.

This fixed it for me. I tried with `npx expo start` before, but that doesn't include the native components required for @react-native-voice/voice to work properly. React native voice is like a wrapper around native android and ios components that enable voice recording, so it will need those native components to be build first otherwise it can't work hence getting all the nulls.